# Flutter, xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, android-studio

I have a problem with running Flutter app on the iOS simulator using Android Studio. I can successfully run the app on a physical device using Xcode and Android Studio. I can also run the app on the iOS simulator using Xcode. I t

Output from Android Studio:

```
Launching lib/main_player_app_dev.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           38.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    .
    .
    .
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-BY)
    • Flutter version 2.5.2 at /Users/uladzislaudubouski/Documents/Software/flutter/flutter_new
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 3595343e20 (7 days ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ac856380f
    • Dart version 2.14.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/uladzislaudubouski/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Uladzislau’s iPhone (mobile) • 00008030-001A451A1EA0402E            • ios            • iOS 15.0.1 19A348
    • iPhone 13 (mobile)           • DC99A040-C177-4892-B8BA-B94DFADB023B • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      94.0.4606.71
    ! Error: Uladzislau’s iPhone is busy: Making the device ready for development. Xcode will continue when
      Uladzislau’s iPhone is finished. (code -10)

• No issues found!
```

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Can you connect only one device to run? because here there is 3 connected device in your system.

Comment: I have only one connected physical device (iphone se 2020).

Comment: Can you go through your problem with it?
https://fluttercorner.com/xcodebuild-warning-using-the-first-of-multiple-matching-destinations/